# Circumvent frequent repaint()-calls for tile-based game

Tags: java, awt

I just started to work on a tile-based simulation game (3D but the graphics will all be 2D pngs/bitmaps). The graphical concept is similar to e.g. gnomoria. I managed to implement the graphical part of the world using a custom subclass from Panel (AWT) that draws the cubes starting at the lowest level left back and works its way up. This way the images of the cubes fit together correctly, but the painting takes too long for a 196*196*100 cubes big world.

Now what I'm asking for are methods to circumvent the repainting of the whole world everytime it changes a little bit.

I think I got a decent idea for the changing process of a single top layer block by just repainting the visible side (either top/left/right) so that it isnt necessary to repaint all the following cubes. But what I'm unable to solve is the repaint whenever I'm moving the screen, i.e. moving the world using a KeyListener. My first idea was to just move the Panel in the Frame but that didn't solve the problem as it still redraws everything if I move the world. Btw I already use hardware acceleration which accelerated :D things a bit, but it is still far away from the goal.

The current result is that the Panel moves, but as soon as something enters the screen that was offscreen before, it repaints this section. The repaint is quite fast but not fast enough to not be visible and disturbing.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: I don't think that this would help you... I need a whole new concept and that will make most of my topic related code useless. If you think it would help, I will upload it though :)

Comment: Are you familiar with clip regions.  They are rectangular areas that let you specify which area of the screen to paint based on recent updates.  You can specify them in calls to `repaint()` and using the `graphics context`.

Comment: Let's say I know the basics... But how do I use them correctly in this case? If I want to move the whole metacube, where do I need to place the clip? Over the whole structure? The Edge? Every single cube? How do I use them properly?

Comment: Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html.  It includes various aspect of graphics and painting.

Comment: OK, I tried it with clipping but I think it is the wrong concept because I had to clip basically the whole area and thus it didn't change anything. The problem is that if you move a map let's say to the left, the whole map looks different after that. It is the same picture but everything needs to be moved a bit to the left. I can't clip the edge that comes into the screen because that is only part of the area that changes. Is there a way to save the whole current drawn image and redraw it with different coordinates? Or do you have another idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you actually drawing the image yourself?  If so , you can store it in a Polygon class and then translate the image to a different location.  I would need to see a [mcve] though.

Comment: I think I got it :D Instead of directly using paint on the panel, I paint the whole world in a BufferedImage. After that I draw this Image to the Panel which is of course way faster than painting the small cubes. To move the world, I just repaint this Image to other coordinates and by using a clip in the size of the screen. The only thing the needs time at the moment is the first rendering of the blocks but that is ok, every game has a loading screen. The only thing I ask myself at the moment is, why the game needs 2.7 GB of RAM if the big Picture only has 7 MB when saved as PNG.